# How would I translate the following Java backward counting loop into Scala?

Tags: scala

The following Java code is a very simple piece of code, but what are the equivalent constructs in Scala?

```
for (int i=10; i> 0; i-=2) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: There is no direct equivalent in Scala. See *Cruel.scala* attached to  http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/optimizing-simple-fors-tp2545502p2546347.html for an approximation. May be Rex can post it here too as an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you also need the code to be as fast as it was in Java.

If you just want it to work, you can use:

```
for (i <- 10 until 0 by -2) println(i);
```

(where `until` means *omit the final entry* and `to` means *include the final entry*, as if you used `>` or `>=`).

However, there will be some modest overhead for this; the `for` loop is a more general construct in Scala than in Java, and though it could be optimized in principle, in practice it hasn't yet (not in the core distribution through 2.9; the ScalaCL plugin will probably optimize it for you, however).

For a println, the printing will take *much* longer than the looping, so it's okay.  But in a tight loop which you know is a performance bottleneck, you'll need to use while loops instead:

```
var i = 10
while (i > 0) {
  println(i)
  i -= 2
}
```

Comment: instead of while-loops tail-recursive methods are preferred in a functional language like Scala.

Comment: @Antoras - Tail-recursive methods are less clear and syntactically clunkier for simple indexed iteration: `var i=0; while (i<N) { f(i); i+=1 }` vs. `def x(i: Int) { f(i); if (i<N) x(i+1) }; x(0)`.  If you want to do the same iteration twice, then yes, a method is good.

Comment: Ok, that is true. Recursion makes more sense when the method returns a value: `def x(i: Int, v: SomeValue): SomeValue = if (i == 10) v else x(i+1, NewValue)`

Comment: `def sum(a: Array[Int]) = { var i,s = 0; while (i<a.length) { s += a(i); i += 1 }; s }` vs. `def sum(a: Array[Int], i: Int = 0; s: Int = 0): Int = if (i >= a.length) s else sum(a, i+1, s+a(i))` still looks like a win for iteration to me.

Answer (score 7):

To iterate from 10 to 0 (exclusive) in steps of 2 in Scala, you can create a Range using the `until` and `by` methods and then iterate over them in a for loop:

```
for(i <- 10 until 0 by -2)
```

Comment: `to` is a member of RichInt (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.RichInt) which creates a  Range.Inclusive (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range$$Inclusive.html), where `by` is defined; it creates another `Inclusive`   
`i` is implicitly converted to a RichInt to enable this process to start

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can do as well:

```
(0 to 4).map (10 - 2 * _)
```

or

```
List(10, 8, 6, 4, 2) foreach println
```

or how about

```
(2 to 10 by 2).reverse
```